# Javascript hover issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-events

When I user either jQuery's `.hover()` or Javascript's `mouseenter()`, the event triggers not only when the mouse enters the element, but also when the mouse crosses any element within that element. How can I stop this so that it only triggers when the mouse enters or exits that element, with the elements children having no effect on the event?

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            introAnimation();
            
            $('#nav-item1').hover(function() {
                $('#createSub').slideDown(300);
            });
            $('#nav-item1').mouseout(function() {
                $('#createSub').slideUp(300);
            });
            
            $('#nav-item2').hover(function() {
                $('#manageSub').slideDown(300);
            });
            $('#nav-item2').mouseout(function() {
                $('#manageSub').slideUp(300);
            });
            $('#nav-item3').hover(function() {
                $('#storeSub').slideDown(300);
            });
            $('#nav-item3').mouseout(function() {
                $('#storeSub').slideUp(300);
            });
        });
```

Comment: That's not true; only `mouseover()` does that.   Please show an example.

Comment: Can you provide a sample? That is not the default behavior. Child elements are within the parent, so hover should not be effected by children.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be acting as I described anymore, but you can view an example (the left navigation bar) here: http://developer.crawford.com/

Comment: The `hover` function accepts two functions, one for when the mouse gets in the element, and the other for when it gets out.

Answer (score 3):

Hover has a method for unhovering. No need for the mouseout event, which gets fired when you mouse over a nested child element:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        introAnimation();

        $('#nav-item1').hover(function() {
            $('#createSub').slideDown(300);
        },function() {
            $('#createSub').slideUp(300);
        });
        $('#nav-item2').hover(function() {
            $('#manageSub').slideDown(300);
        },function() {
            $('#manageSub').slideUp(300);
        });
        $('#nav-item3').hover(function() {
            $('#storeSub').slideDown(300);
        },function() {
            $('#storeSub').slideUp(300);
        });
    });
```

Comment: great suggestion, I didn't even realize this.

Answer (score 0):

add this within the handler:

```
if( ev.target !== this ){ return; }
```

`ev.target` is what the mouse event triggers on.  `this` is what you bound the event to